# EN_UPDATE does not send to the subclassed edit box procedure

Tags: windows, winapi

I have subclassed Edit control window procedure and then found out it no longer
sent the EN_UPDATE.

Am I missing something , and could somebody suggest me a workaround on this one?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK EditBoxProc_textbox3( HWND hwnd, UINT message , WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
  int previous_position = 0 ;
  WCHAR previous_text [1024];
  WCHAR current_text [1024];


  switch (message)
  {

    case WM_CREATE:
       previous_text[0] = L'\0';
       current_text[0] = L'\0';
       break;

    case EN_SETFOCUS:
      // :TODO: read the current text of the textbox3 and update textbox2 
      // text according to it.                                             //
      Edit_Enable(hwndTextBox2,FALSE);
      break;

    case EN_UPDATE:
      MessageBox(NULL,L"EN_UPDATE", lpszAppName,MB_OK);
      GetWindowText( hwndTextBox3,  current_text ,1024);
      if( is_valid_textbox3(current_text))
      {
        wcscpy(previous_text,current_text);
        previous_position = LOWORD(Edit_GetSel(hwndTextBox3));
        update_textbox2(NULL);

      }else
      {
        SetWindowText(hwndTextBox3, previous_text );
        Edit_SetSel(hwndTextBox3,previous_position, previous_position);
      }  
      break;

    case EN_KILLFOCUS:
      Edit_Enable(hwndTextBox2,TRUE);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return CallWindowProc(edit_old_wndproc_textbox3,hwnd,message,\
           wParam,lParam);
}
```

Comment: This is a notification message. It is sent to the parent control. Where is your code that reflects it on to the edit control? Also, your local variables `previous_text` and `current_text` won't retain values from invocation to invocation of the window proc. They have automatic storage.

Comment: I've learn the lesson. After 2 hrs of thinking and thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and then found out it no longer sent the EN_UPDATE

It never sent EN_UPDATE in the first place.  It is a notification message that's actually sent as a WM_COMMAND message.  And it is sent to the parent of the Edit control, not the control itself.  Same goes for EN_SET/KILLFOCUS.

The design philosophy here is that an Edit control can simply be put on, say, a dialog.  And the custom code that makes the dialog behave in a certain way is written in the parent window's procedure with no requirement to subclass the control.  Which is fine but it makes it difficult to create a customized edit control that can have its own behavior.  Or in other words, it makes it hard to componentize an edit control.  The EN_SET/KILLFOCUS notifications are not a problem, you can simple detect their corresponding WM_SET/KILLFOCUS messages.  But you'll hit the wall on EN_UPDATE, the control doesn't send any message like that to itself.  Only the parent window can detect it.

Componentizing an edit control is pretty desirable and actively pursued by object-oriented class libraries like Winforms and Qt.  They have a class wrapper for the control (TextBox, QLineEdit) that has a virtual method that can be overridden (OnTextChanged, changeEvent) so that the control can be customized into a derived class with its own behavior.  And generate an event (aka signal) that anybody can subscribe to, not just the parent (TextChanged, textChanged).  To make that work, the parent window needs to participate.  When it gets the WM_COMMAND message, it must echo the notification back to the child control.  Either by sending a special message back or by calling a virtual method on the child class.

You can of course implement this yourself as well, albeit that you are liable of reinventing such a class library.  Consider using an existing one instead.