# win32 treeview handle expand or collapse event in the treeview wndproc not it's parent

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview

I'm working with the tree control i wanted to handle item expansion or collapsing, finally i found that the tree send' an notification TVN_ITEMEXPANDING to it's parent window, as mentioned in this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773537(v=vs.85).aspx

I'm writing a tree class that will be reused in other windows and inherited i want to handle that event the wndProc of the tree independently of it's parent. like .NET

how can this be done??

I'm inheriting from TTreeWindow class of OWL library
I'm now depending on the dialog that hosts the tree it receives the notification in its wndProc

Comment: Same basic question [as this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15719584/17034)

Comment: sorry it's not a shame to keep learning things tell if they are so basic

Comment: You're welcome, don't mention it.  English is a tricky language, it is not always a put-down.

Comment: Thanks you are the best scientific knowledge exchange community in the internet it's a big honor for me to learn from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make Win32 controls send notifications to the control rather than its parent. That is simply how Win32 notification messages work.

What frameworks like WinForms, VCL etc. do is to arrange that parent controls *reflect* notification messages back to the child control.

I guess that OWL does not do this notification message reflection. If you are going to use a framework, it seldom makes sense to swim against the tide. I suggest that you would be better off following the framework standard approach.

Comment: Thanks for the nice response